# Get html of a table in TinyMCE (using the table plugin)

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor with the table plugin loaded (I'm using the TinyMCE Advanced Wordpress plugin). I have to get a selected table's HTML code (a table that you are currently editing - the on you have resize controls on). With normal text I can use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent()`, but this is not working when dealing with a table. What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();`. If this is a table element you got your table and will be able to get the html using

```
var node = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
var html = node.innerHTML;
// now you will only need to take care of the surrounding table element
// something like "<table>"+ html +"</table>"; maybe having a look at node.attributes
```

Comment: Thanks. The final solution was a bit longer: `$(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode()).parents('table.mceItemTable:first')`

Comment: right, that one is the easiest way using jQuery to get the whole parent

Comment: I get an invalid error character message when trying to use a jQuery function. How can I make jQuery available in my editor_plugin.js? @Thariama - with your solution I get the `tbody` tag and not the `table` one, any ideas how to get the table one?

Comment: $(node).parents('table').first()